# unable to delete a Global Page

Tags: oracle-apex-18.2

I want to delete a Global Page on APEX (18.2) but I am getting an Internal Error.

***Debug logs:***

> Error: ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
>   ORA-02292: integrity constraint (APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_USER_INT_PAGE_FK) violated - child record found

I can delete child records manually but couldn't find any trace. Any idea?

Comment: To facilitate this in the builder, first I needed to clear the global page associated with the user interface using: update apex_180200.WWV_FLOW_USER_INTERFACES set global_page_id = null where flow_id =1000 and global_page_id = 0;

Answer (score 0):

as I know, you can't delete a global page. it will be created by default when you create a new application.

Comment: I couldn't even change the page number of it gave up already, now I have a global page that isn't page zero :)